# How to combine several JasperPrint objects to have one report with mixed page orientation

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The `jasperPrint` object has portrait orientation, but `jasperPrint2` object has landscape orientation. I want to combine the two jasperprints to produce ONE pdf file but keeping their original orientation. When i add the jasperPrint2's pages to the jasperPrint then the final jasperPrint has portrait orientation... I tested the `jasperPrint.setOrientation(JasperReport.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` but nothing changed.

How can i produce ONE pdf file from the two jasperprints keeping their original orientation?

I have the following code :

```java
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportFile2.getPath());
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, conn);

JasperReport report2 = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportFile.getPath());
jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report2, parameters, conn);

List pages = jasperPrint2.getPages();
for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {
    JRPrintPage object = (JRPrintPage) pages.get(j);
    jasperPrint.addPage(object);
}
```

Comment: You can look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564163/how-to-collate-multiple-jrxml-jasper-reports-into-a-one-single-pdf-output-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by doing a batch export.

```
//put all the jasperPrints you want to be combined into a pdf in this list
List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();

JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportFile2.getPath());
jasperPrintList.add(JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, conn));

JasperReport report2 = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportFile.getPath());
jasperPrintList.add(JasperFillManager.fillReport(report2, parameters, conn));

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();       
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();       
//this sets the list of jasperPrint objects to be exported and merged
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrintList);
//the bookmarks is a neat extra that creates a bookmark for each jasper print
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_CREATING_BATCH_MODE_BOOKMARKS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);     
exporter.exportReport();        
return baos.toByteArray();
```