# How to collate multiple jrxml jasper reports into a one single pdf output file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have to prepare reports using five different sql queries. Each query will give out one report table.

So I wrote 5 jrxml files each corresponding to one of the above query with their own headings, title settings, footers, pagenumbers, etc.

Now, I am able to compile, print and export each of the above jrxmls into 5 different pdfs.

However, client wants all the reports collated into one single pdf. That is in the final pdf, first four pages will be say report one, next five pages report two, then report three and so on and so forth.

1) How to achieve this ?

2) Each report has page number as 1/4, 2/4, 3/4 etc. Where the second part i.e. the complete page number is evaluated with evaluation time as report. So when I will collate all reports in single pdf (if possible), will it also be possible to re-number the pages in justification to final pdf ?

Based on the answer below, I did the following in my java class and it works:

```
 try
            {
            JasperReport jreport1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input1);
            JasperPrint jprint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport1, new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
            //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, "/home/ashutosh/Desktop/desktop/nikunj/JasperTestApp/output/mytest.pdf");

            JasperReport jreport2 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input2);
            JasperPrint jprint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport2, new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());

            JasperReport jreport3 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input3);
            JasperPrint jprint3 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport3, new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());

            List<JasperPrint> jprintlist = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();

            jprintlist.add(jprint1);
            jprintlist.add(jprint2);
            jprintlist.add(jprint3);

            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jprintlist);

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/ashutosh/Desktop/desktop/nikunj/JasperTestApp/output/mytestbatch.pdf"));

            exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
            exporter.exportReport();

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Above: input1, input2, input3 are string paths to input jrxmls

Where my JRXML files just print three messages: Hello World 1, Hello World 2, Hello World 3.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport
  PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
  "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">

<jasperReport name="Simple_Report">
 <detail>
    <band height="20">
      <staticText>
        <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
        <text><![CDATA[Hello World One!]]></text>
      </staticText>
    </band>
  </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Alex K's answer is good. You should also be able to get what you want by putting the individual reports into subreports of one master report. It will be more work, but it would allow you to handle the page numbering requirement. You should definitely vote for this as well. It would cover exactly what you are describing: http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/tracker/view.php?id=4178

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can take advantage of exporting the whole jasperprint list:

```java
List jpList = new ArrayList();
jpList.add(JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("build/reports/Report1.jrprint")); 
...
JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter(); 
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jpList); 
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, stream); 
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: @NikunjChauhan The sample [is here](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html). The folder `demo\samples\batchexport` from JasperReports distribution package.

Comment: @Wojtek O. : How to define jpList ?? Is it a simple List of jprint objects ?

Comment: @AlexK: Can you please re paste the link... its not there.. thanks!

Comment: @AlexK: Please see my updates.. there is still something missing!

Comment: `@Wojtek O. ` Ya , I can print all list of `JasperReports` in single pdf ,
But for each reports it go for new page in `PDF` So how can i prevent this .. I want to print this all report in single page of PDF bcz it not contain more data

Comment: @ankit337 then there is no easier way of doing that other than just adapting you report template to hold all the data necessary.

Comment: `@Wojtek O.` Thanks for responding ,But i have 5 or 6 table (Number of table is dynamic ) and i want to get data(2 to 4 row from each table ) from all table in one report .,, so can you suggest any way ?

Comment: The code in answer is [deprecated](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#JASPER_PRINT_LIST) since version 5.6, I have added an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38869089/5292302) of non deprecated code.

Comment: setParameter is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

> This answer is to help users with **JASPER REPORT VERSION >5.6** (latest
>   versions), hence remove the deprecated code.

Since jasper-report 5.6 `JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST` is [deprecated](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#JASPER_PRINT_LIST) the current code of Wojtek Owczarczyk [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564737/5292302) is:

```
List<JasperPrint> jpList = new ArrayList<>();
//add your JasperPrint's from loading jrprint or more 
//commonly filling report with JasperFillManager.fillReport 

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jpList)); //Set as export input
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(stream)); //Set output stream
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
//set your configuration
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Note: the export with best quality (JRGraphics2DExporter) does not work with many jasperPrints. Ref: source code of JRGraphics2DExporter

Answer (score 1):

Page numbers without itext...

```
private void drawPageNumbers(List<JasperPrint> listJasperPrint, int totalPages) throws JRException {

    int pageCount = 0;
    int posY = 0;
    int posX = 0;

    for (JasperPrint jasperPrint : listJasperPrint) {

        if (jasperPrint.getOrientation() == JRReport.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            posY = 805;
            posX = 472;
        }

        if (jasperPrint.getOrientation() == JRReport.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            posY = 558;
            posX = 717;
        }

        for (Object obj : jasperPrint.getPages()) {

            pageCount++;
            JRPrintPage page = (JRPrintPage) obj;

            JRPrintText textTotalPages = new JRTemplatePrintText(new JRTemplateText(
                    jasperPrint.getOrigins()[0], jasperPrint.getDefaultStyleProvider()));
            textTotalPages.setX(posX + 54);
            textTotalPages.setY(posY);
            textTotalPages.setWidth(40);
            textTotalPages.setHeight(16);
            textTotalPages.setText(" " + totalPages);
            page.addElement(textTotalPages);

            JRPrintText textPageNumber = new JRTemplatePrintText(new JRTemplateText(
                    jasperPrint.getOrigins()[0], jasperPrint.getDefaultStyleProvider()));
            textPageNumber.setX(posX);
            textPageNumber.setY(posY);
            textPageNumber.setWidth(80);
            textPageNumber.setHeight(16);
            textPageNumber.setText("Página " + pageCount + " de");
            page.addElement(textPageNumber);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
JasperPrint jp1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportFile1,reportParams,Connection);  
JasperPrint jp2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportFile2,reportParams,Connection);  
for (int j = 0; j < jp1.getPages().size(); j++) {  
    //Add First report to second report
    jp2.addPage((JRPrintPage) jp1.getPages().get(j));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(iReport example)

Part I:

- create a new blank jasper report as a wrapper report for different reports
- data adapter = One empty record - Empty Rows
- click "New..."
- choose "empty rows"
- click "next"
- number of empty records = 1 (so you will simulate on record and only ONE detail band will be printed)
- so the blank report is ready
  When you call this report out of your JAVA program, first open a data connection to the database and exchange this connection in the background. SubReports of our wrapper report can inherit this connection via parameters!

Part 2)

- add for every report you want to embed a new detail band.
- each detail band contains a subreport (link to the other standalone report of course)
- set the property "run to bottom" to "True" in the subreport definition of our wrapper report

this concept works for me.
depending on parameters, you can switch different bands on or off, of course.