# Jasperreports add another report how to deal with pagination

Tags: java, pagination, jasper-reports, reporting

i have a invoice i need to add a report as last page in the report `a report with multiples  images with severals sizes.` everything works `OK` but i am facing the `Pagination problem` because the first report can have from `1...N pages` and the pagination is `OK` but when i add the other reports by example will appear in `Page 3` i can see still.

Page 1 from 1.

i was wondering if it is possible to relate the numerations in the 2 reports to act good something like

First report [3 pages].

```
Page 1: Page 1 from 3
Page 2: Page 2 from 3
Page 3: Page 3 from 3
```

Second report [1 page].

```
Page 1: Page 4 from 4
```

some code.

```
final ArrayList<JasperPrint>jaspers=new ArrayList<JasperPrint>(Arrays.asList(jasperPrint,imageStreaming));
final ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
final JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();    
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST,jaspers);
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_CREATING_BATCH_MODE_BOOKMARKS,true);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,arrayOutputStream);         
exporter.exportReport();            
arrayOutputStream.close();
```

any trick or resource or workaround is hugely appreciate.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Try to search on *SO* - a similar post was some time ago

Comment: i didn't find anything alex so sad.

Comment: Sorry. I'm talking about this post: [How to collate multiple jrxml jasper reports into a one single pdf output file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8564163/876298). But the link http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/tracker/view.php?id=4178 (see comment by @mdahlman) is not available.

Comment: Try to search on http://community.jaspersoft.com/. I've found this one: [Page numbering for multiple reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/520259/page-numbering-multiple-reports). Several posts contains this link: jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/tracker/view.php?id=4178

Comment: Please share the result of your research