# How to combine two Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new for Jasperreport. I have two different reports which print in pdf form. How can I  combine them so that they can be printed into one report?

Comment: This post can help you: [How do I add a second page in Jaspersoft iReport Designer 4.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11830904/876298). More info: [Batch Export Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html#batchexport)

Comment: Thanks. I use subreport so two different report can combine them successfully. Thanks for your good suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to collate multiple jrxml jasper reports into a one single pdf output file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564163/how-to-collate-multiple-jrxml-jasper-reports-into-a-one-single-pdf-output-file)