# Jasper report excel export output

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have total 5 reports in 5 different files and i want to make only single excel file which contains these five reports and five different sheets how it will be possible with jasper report?

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to collate multiple jrxml jasper reports into a one single pdf output file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564163/how-to-collate-multiple-jrxml-jasper-reports-into-a-one-single-pdf-output-file)

Comment: we have 5 different sheets in excel so we develop 5 different jrxml files and we exported these 5 reports and then try to merge them in one single excel file report/sheet.

Comment: and one more point related to this is that i want to ignore columnGroups from repeating in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating 5 reports just use one report and set the property `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet` to `true`.

Then just rename them with `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name`
and use the Page Break element

Search on the internet for more information if needed. There are actually a lot of examples for this.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create JasperPrint objects for each sheet as you normally would.

```
JasperPrint firstSheet = ...;
JasperPrint secondSheet = ...;
JasperPrint thirdSheet = ...;
JasperPrint fourthSheet = ...;
JasperPrint fifthSheet = ...;
```

Now JasperPrint already have the datasource at this point. Use the Arraylist to add the JasperPrint object and the exporter will use each object to create a sheet

```
JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();

ArrayList<JasperPrint> list = new  ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
list.add(firstSheet); 
list.add(secondSheet);
list.add(thirdSheet); 
list.add(fourthSheet);
list.add(fifthSheet); 
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(list)); 
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputFile));
exporter.exportReport();
```

And you need to use `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRXlsxExporter` as import