# How to change page orientation with JR API

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to change report view ***Portrait*** to ***Landscape***.

I have used this method:

```java
jasperPrint.setOrientation(OrientationEnum.LANDSCAPE);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428619/change-orientation-of-jasperprint

Comment: @praba Did you fix this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

in i-report it is easy to do:

click on the top item in the report inspector and use the pull down in the proprieties to change to landscape

in code here is what you have to do

portrait (a4)

`http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">`

landscape

`http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">`

Answer (score 0):

```
jasperPrint.setOrientation(OrientationEnum.LANDSCAPE);
jasperDesign.setPageHeight(Page.Page_A4_Landscape().getHeight());
jasperDesign.setPageWidth(Page.Page_A4_Landscape().getWidth());
```

This was useful for me. I hope it will help you.